# How to fix phase cancellation in an audio file?

Tags: phase, phase-alignment

I have an audio file of a song from a friend and it has very bad phase cancellation. I noticed that after I opened the file in Adobe Audition and looked at the phase analysis window.

[image: As you can see, the phase cancellation is real.]

I already tried the "automatic phase correction" tool but it didn't improve anything because it only tries to detect and correct time shift and balance between left and right channel, not the phase cancellation itself.

Is there a way I can correct the phase problems?

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't. The phase problem was locked into the file during the mix process.

Comment: Oooh! 3D Extra-Wide Stereoizyfier. I wonder what that does??

Answer (score 0):

I personally hate stereoizers too but I think my friend didn't use any of it because not everything in the song is stereo seperated. Just some synthesizers are really out of phase, I mean REALLY out of phase (when you convert the song in mono the synths are basically inaudible or they sound like a bad drunk flanger) but anyways thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, my friend recomposed his song and just made the problematic synths mono.

[image: Looks fine to me.]

Now there is almost no phase cancellation. When you're in doubt, go mono.

I think there is a good reason why you should mix in mono in the first place.